# find number of 'p' tags in a div and iterate through them to scrape the underlying text using python xpath

Tags: python, xpath

I've tried this;

```
no_of_p_tags = 10 # I'm assuming this. Yet to figure out how to find this.
for x in range(1,no_of_p_tags + 1)
    test = content.xpath('//*[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/p[x]/span/text()')
    print test
```

(1) How do I find the number of 'p' tags in a div and (2) iterate through them to scrape the underlying text using python xpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the `p` tags instead of their text content; by using `p[span]` we only select `p` tags that have a `span` element as a direct child:

```
ptags_with_span = content.xpath('//*[@id="ciHomeContentlhs"]/div[4]/div[2]/div[1]/p[span]')
no_of_p_tags = len(ptags_with_span)
for ptag in ptags_with_span:
    print ptag.xpath('./span/text()')
```